# обновление анимации при прокрутке вверх

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть сайт http://infocazy.beget.tech у блоков есть анимация , если прокрутить полностью вниз и нажать кнопку на вверх анимации больше не будет, как сделать что бы анимация заново работала

Answer (score 0):

Сделать проверку.
Типо, если `Animation == 1` - проигрывать анимацию.
И каждый раз при `$.scrollTop == 0` выставлять `Animation = 0`.

Но думаю есть вариант проще)